# Why i cant create Font variable with SFML C++?

Tags: c++, sfml

SFML C++ Font.cpp.obj Error

When I try to create Text variable I've got 22 errors like 
Error LNK2019   reference to an unresolved external character _FT_Stroker_Set in funk "private: class sf::Glyph __thiscall sf::Font::loadGlyph(unsigned int,unsigned int,bool,float)const " (?loadGlyph@Font@sf@@ABE?AVGlyph@2@II_NM@Z) sfmlempty   C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\sfmlempty\sfmlempty\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(Font.cpp.obj) 1

Comment: You are having linker issues, not compiler issues. You are not correctly linking the libraries that define the symbols you use.

Comment: That's a linker issue. Recheck linking in the project settings. If your still having issues vcpkg is a good tool for managing c++ librarys.